# $E[X^4]$ for binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $n,p$, the expectations $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$ are given be $np$ and $n(n-1)p^2+np$, respectively.

What about $E[X^4]$? Is there a table where I can look it up? Calculating it using the definition of expectation looks like a lot of work. Or is there a good way to calculate it?

Comment: It is a bit easier if you compute $e_3 = E[X(X-1)(X-2)]$ and $e_4 = E[X(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)]$. Then, you can express $E[X^3]$ from $e_3$ and  $E[X^4]$ from $e_4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can create a table if you know the [moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$ *i.e.* $$M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$$

because $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}M_X(t)|_{t=0}=E[X^n].$

*Hint*: Show that $M_X(t)=(e^tp+(1-p))^n$ for binomial $X$ with parameters $n,p.$